# Get tagging to work on AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I am trying to tag commit hash and app version onto the ECS service to make it easier for developers to identify the service with the code.

But I get this error

```
+ aws ecs tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:12344556677:service/master-web-dev-WebECSServices --tags key=COMMITHASH,value=85491def key=VERSION,value=0.2.4
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the TagResource operation: Long arn format must be used for tagging operations
```

Is there any problem with the ARN? Why do I always get this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because your ECS service was created before tagging was available for ECS services.

See this blog post by AWS on how to migrate to the new ARN format. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2/

Comment: If you have a lot of ECS services already it might be a lot of work to recreate everything to take advantage of tags.